# How do i change git bash to show from left to right

Tags: git, git-bash, right-to-left

I'm using windows in Hebrew (right-to-left language) and I've downloaded git,
in the git bash the text starts in the top right of the window instead of the top left.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't do it.

If you want you can install git and add it to your path and then you will be able to use it from the power shell or cmd which will be displayed based upon your local OS language direction.